# Jacoco Android createDebugCoverageReport not found

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I want to run my tests in Android app and create coverage reports, so I added Jacoco configuration into my build.gradle file, but it doesn't work.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "mm"
        minSdkVersion 12
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/freemarker.jar')
    compile files('libs/greendao-1.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/raygun4android-1.1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.11'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }

}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.11.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacoco {
    version "0.7.1.201405082137"
}


jacoco {
    toolVersion "0.7.1.201405082137"
}

def coverageSourceDirs = [
        'src/main/java',
]

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: './build/intermediates/classes/debug',
            excludes: ['**/R*.class',
                       '**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
                       '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
                       '**/*$ViewInjector*.class'
            ])
    sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
    executionData = files("$buildDir/jacoco/testDebug.exec")
    doFirst {
        new File("$buildDir/intermediates/classes/").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know, there is issue with gradle version 1.3.0 and with 1.3.1 it should work normally, however with 1.3.1 I get `Task 'createDebugCoverageReport' not found in root project`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to enable the `testCoverageEnabled` :

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        isTestCoverageEnabled true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        isTestCoverageEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP. I have testCoverageEnabled set to true, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Do you have it included in the required buildType of the module(s) where the source code is?

Comment: @DannyChia which device you are using? Android version, company

Comment: But how to enable it for domain module (java-library)? We don't have `buildTypes` on java library.

Comment: I cannot add the property and enabled in it says                        "Unresolved reference: testCoverageEnabled" any ideas ?